# Defining policies inside controllers in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, controllers, policies

Sails.js (0.9v) controllers has a 
***_config function*** to override configs from config file.

is there any _policies function to define the policies inside the controllers itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Policies can already be specified on per-controller basis in the `/config/policies.js` file, so there's no benefit in having the configuration exist inside the controller file as well.  See the comments inside `/config/policies` for information on how to attach a policy to a specific controller or action.  Also keep in mind that in Sails v0.10, the `_config` key is still valid inside controller files, but the configuration properties should be put at the top level, *not* under `blueprints`, e.g.:

```
_config: {
   rest: false,
   actions: false,
   shortcuts: false
}
```

These will override the settings in your `/config/blueprints.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think nope. You can override the controller config but not create policy inside it. E.g.

```
...
_config: {
  blueprints: {
    rest: true, ....
  }
}
```

Please define policies as middleware in the policies folder.

Comment: starting from sails 0.10 this `blueprints` should be omitted as @Scott pointed out